# Why is assigning 'int constant -> byte variable' valid, but 'long constant -> int variable' is not?

Tags: java, casting, primitive

I have this code snippet:

```
int i = 5l; // not valid (compile error)
byte b = 5; // valid
```

What do you think about it?

Why?

Comment: Look Over [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is defined in [the JLS #5.2 (Assignment conversion)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> If the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int, a narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

so:

```
byte b = 5; //ok: b is a byte and 5 is an int between -128 and 127
byte b = 1000; //not ok: 1000 is an int but is not representable as a byte (> 127)
byte b = 5L; //not ok: 5L is a long (and not a byte, short, char or int)
int i = 5L; //not ok: i is not a byte, short or char
int i = 5; byte b = i; //not ok: i is not a constant
final int i = 5; byte b = i; //ok: i is a constant and b is a byte
```

Comment: +1. You can add that the last statement compiles because the `final` values are inlined.

Comment: The "if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int" appearing just before the quoted statement is perhaps also significant, as the closely related statement `byte b = 5l;` won't work.

Comment: @assylias, I meant `inlined`. It means the compiler puts the value in the code as if you had typed it there i.e. the byte code will read `byte b = 5;`

Comment: @kocko `static final` are inlined but I don't think that non-static `final` variables are.

Comment: @assylias, I think they are. If you have a `final` variable defined within a method and then you implement an anonymous class and pass the `final` variable, it will be inlined (this is why it compiles)

Comment: @kocko I just checked and it's not the case (static final is inlined but local final variable is not). Tested with Java 8 but I am pretty sure the result would be the same with Java 7.

Comment: How did you test it ?

Comment: @m4xdev thank you for your edit but it contains wrong information. `5` is not a byte constant, it is an `int` - and there is no concept of `short` in java...

Comment: @assylias mmh sorry, i saw this from a C++ point of view, feel free to correct me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just assuming here because there is unlikely to be a definitive answer.

For

```
int i = 5l;
```

the compiler assumes there is a good reason you wrote `5l` and not `5` and so it is an error.

For

```
byte b = 5;
```

there is no `byte` literal way of writing 5 and so it would be needlessly pedantic to insist you write `(byte) 5` every time and in fact it would be error prone.

```
byte b = 222;        // is an error
byte b = (byte) 222; // is NOT an error
```

Answer (score 1):

Language specification allows that (note that 5, 127 or 128 is an integer literal):

```
    byte b = 127;
```

this will generate error:

```
    byte b = 128;
```

this is called implicit narrowing primitive conversion, and is allowed by JLS:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of
>   type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

so, below is compiler error because of above statement

```
int i = 5l;
```

`5l` is long and not  ***constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int***. Also it fails to be correct becasue it is an int, bacause ***if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char***.

Comment: That does not explain why the first statement does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

In first case

```
int i = 5l;  // trying to allocate 64bits in 32 bits space. Err
```

where as

```
byte b = 5; //  byte can represented in a  range is -128 to 127. Compiles fine
```

Comment: 5-( int - 4 byte) -> b(byte -1 byte).

Comment: 1<4 - fist case 4<8 - second case

Comment: @gstackoverflow Sorry, but wrong assumption. So how can you write/represent a byte there ?

Comment: *So how can you write/represent a byte there ?* - LOOOOOOOOOL

Comment: @gstackoverflow So you are laughing at the point you are missing?? :)  range of value `-128 to 127` fits in one byte.

Comment: It was very exactly note

Comment: @gstackoverflow Thanks for accepting that point at least. Happy coding :)

Comment: I didn't think about postfixes

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind right now why `int i = 5l;` is not possible,  because the range of long is bigger than int range and thus putting long value in variable that of int could not be possible.

int range: **-2147483648… 2147483648**, and
long range: **-2^63… 2^63-1**

Comment: `5` is an int, ints have a larger range than bytes and still `byte b = 5;` compiles...

Comment: Of course it would be compiled because byte b = 5, number 5 is in range that byte itself can take. The range of byte is -128… 127. That is valid. I'm not taking part into that sentence, but into int i = 5l;

Answer (score 0):

as according to my understanding,

Because you have to cast the type long to int , for the first option , i.e

```
int i = (int) 5l;
```

and in second case, as the value assignment to byte is same like assignment to int,

you think i am assigning int value to byte here

```
byte b= 5; ????
```

no its not, its getting the value as byte itself, as byte have a range from -128 to 127,

for further detail see [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)